# Create middle lined mask in vector shape

Tags: after-effects, shape

I have a Illustrator vector shape (It has a shape path around it). But I need a mask line in the middle of the shape. The problem with with doing it by drawing a shape line over it is that I can't get the corners right.

I want to use the middle lined mask to do animations with.

[image: This is what I am looking for]

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/49643/how-to-use-after-effects-trim-path-with-an-illustrator-path/49975#49975

Comment: I knew that link already :) I used that for the animating part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Photoshop (or Illustrator), in a new layer above the vector shape, create a solid shape of the mask you want (with rounded corners). Export that layer alone as an image and import into AE.

Use auto-trace to create a mask from it. See https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/creating-shapes-masks.html#create_a_mask_from_channel_values_with_auto_trace